# Using value from Javascript to Ajax

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm trying to get two values (x and y) from a javascript (Virtualjoystick.js) and pass them to a (prototype.js) Ajax script. I've been reading through similar questions and answers both here and on other websites but I'm not really 'getting it'! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a simplified version of what I have so far.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="JavaScripts/prototype.js"></script>
<script src="JavaScripts/virtualjoystick.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="info">
    <span id="result"><b>Joystick:</b> X:0 Y:0</span>
</div>
<div id="container">
<canvas height="300" width="300"></canvas> 
<canvas height="300" width="300"></canvas>
 
<script>
console.log("touchscreen is", VirtualJoystick.touchScreenAvailable() ? "available" : "not available");
  
 var joystick  = new VirtualJoystick({
        container : document.getElementById('container'),
        mouseSupport  : true,
        stationaryBase: true,
        baseX: 150,
        baseY: 150,
        limitStickTravel: true,
        stickRadius: 100

      });
      joystick.addEventListener('touchStart', function(){
        console.log('down')
      })
      joystick.addEventListener('touchEnd', function(){
        console.log('up')
      })

      setInterval(function(){
        var outputEl  = document.getElementById('result');
        outputEl.innerHTML  = '<b>Result:</b> '
          + ' X:'+parseInt(joystick.deltaX())
          + ' Y:'+parseInt(joystick.deltaY())
      }, 1/30 * 1000);
   </script>


</div>

<div>
<form>
 <input type="button" value="On" onClick="go('60.30')" style="font-size:200%;"><br />
 <input type="button" value="Off" onClick="go('0.0')" style="font-size:200%;">
</form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function go(qry) {
     new Ajax.Request('motor_control.py?q='+ qry, 
      {method: 'GET'}
        );
      }
    </script>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

What I need is `parseInt(joystick.deltaX())` and `+parseInt(joystick.deltaY())` from the virtualjoystick.js script to be written to the end of the Ajax.Request. Something like:

```html
new Ajax.Request('motor_control.py?q='+parseInt(joystick.deltaX())
          + '.'+parseInt(joystick.deltaY()),
```

I tried that but it didn't seem to work!

As you can probably tell JavaScript is a foreign language to me, so any help at all would be appreciated.

Comment: "it didn't seem to work" — What did you expect to happen? What actually happened? Were any errors reported in your browser's Developer Tools console? Do you see the HTTP request in the Network tab of the Developer Tools? Was the request constructed as you expect? Did it get a response? Was the status code on the response correct? Was the content of the response correct?

Comment: Nothing happened! And nothing appeared in the logs. My assumption was that my 'attempt' failed! To be honest I didn't think of the Developer Tools console. My experience is all in PHP and Python so the log files is where I start debugging! I'll have a look what the Developer console has to say.

Answer (score -1):

If you are wanting to use plain JavaScript you can use something like the example below. You will have to remember that when using AJAX type function that you will only be able to perform operations on the data retrieved by the function from inside a call back or promise function. Click on the following link to see the Ajax function in action.

[Live Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/XJDs9e7RaFn2BzhyjSMJ)

**JavaScript:**

```
//path to the file you are sending and retrieving data
//this will differ from the Plunker link code because
//I do not have access to the url in your example.
var url = "motor_control.py?q='+ qry";

//call get Ajax function
get(url,function(data){//begin call back function


  //do something with data variable here


  //change the innerHTML of the example id element.
  document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = "I was rendered by an AJAX function!"


});//end call back function

function get(url,fn){//begin ajax function

        var contentType;

        //variable to hold the xmlhttp object
        var xmlhttp = null;


      //if the browser contains the object
      if(window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari

                //create a new XMLHttpRequest object
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }


            //add the event listenter
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){       

      //if the status of the request is good 
      if (xmlhttp.readyState===4 && xmlhttp.status===200){//begin if then

        //get the response text and store it in the data variable
        var data = xmlhttp.responseText;    

        //call the callback function
        fn(data,fn);

        }//end if then             


    };//end function


    //open a the http request
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);

    //set the request header
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type",contentType);

    //send the the request
    xmlhttp.send();  


    }//end get function
```

Comment: You seem to have completely ignored the context of the question in favour of giving a generic introductory Ajax tutorial.

Comment: Why are you setting a `Content-Type` request header on a GET request?

Comment: Why are you supporting IE 6 in 2016?

Comment: Why are you using `arguments[1]` instead of `fn`?

Comment: What is the point of moving `fn(data);` into a function of its own? That just bloats the code.

Comment: Re your edit "you will have pass the the values as http parameters to in the url parameter" — That's what the code in the question already does!

Comment: @Quentin good point about the old code supporting IE6.  I removed the unneeded code.

Comment: @Quentin I can see that he is passing url parameters in his function call. What do not know is if he is using something like the prototype library?  Is that where the Ajax.Request object call is coming from?

Comment: @Quentin I removed the extra function declaration. You are correct it is not really necessary.